# About while statements

Tags: javascript

I have a question. I need to create a script section with a while statement that prints all even numbers between 1 and 100 to the screen.
I am most likely doing it wrong this is what I have

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    Var count= 2;
    while (count<=100) {
document.write (count +"<br />");
++count;
    }
   document.write("<p>You have printed 100 numbers.</p>");
    </script>
```

I am trying to find something that could explain this better I also dont know if I am suppose to use the do while either.

Comment: what does ++count; do?  Is that what you want it to do?

Comment: Have you tried running your script to see what it produces?

Comment: I don't see what your question is. If this is your actual code, though, `Var` is incorrect; it needs to be `var`.

Comment: Yes Dexter and I get nothing.

Comment: You can do everything with `while`, it is the most basic loop... (ok, not 100% true, it would be difficult to loop over object properties I guess).

Comment: Did you also incorporate Gabe's correction? I think it should work with that, depending on what 'work' means to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all **even** numbers from 1 to 100 is

```
var count= 2; //var lowercase!
while (count<=100) {
    document.write (count +"<br />");
    count+=2;
}
```

Comment: even subset between 1 and 100 starts with 2, no? :D

Comment: Yes, but then you would say 'between 1 and 100' (or 101) and not from 1 to 100, because that would suggest than 1 is an even number. ;)

Comment: Well, it's a 'semantic' problem then.. the questioneer asked "..prints all even numbers between 1 and 100 to the screen" .. I assumed that everyone knows that 1 is not even :)

Comment: Btw.. I apologize.."from X to Y", I meant "between X and Y" :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will be more clear using the 'for' loop:

```
for(var count = 2; count <= 100; count += 2) {
    document.write (count +"<br />");
}
```

Comment: But not using a while loop won't get him credit for his homework.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  for (var i = 2; i <= 100; i += 2) { // edit: was i + 2
    document.write(i + '<br />');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @Michael Good spot with the edit, thanks